# Prediction using Fixed Effects

Tags: r, statistics, prediction, lm

I have a simple data set for which I applied a simple linear regression model. Now I would like to use fixed effects to make a better prediction on the model. I know that I could also consider making dummy variables, but my real dataset consist of more years and has more variables so I would like to avoid making dummies.

My data and code is similar to this:

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                   text="CompanyNumber ResponseVariable Year ExplanatoryVariable1 ExplanatoryVariable2
                   1 2.5 2000 1 2
                   1 4 2001 3 1
                   1 3 2002 5 7
                   2 1 2000 3 2
                   2 2.4 2001 0 4
                   2 6 2002 2 9
                   3 10 2000 8 3")

library(lfe)
library(caret)
fe <- getfe(felm(data = data, ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2 | Year))
fe
lm.1<-lm(ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2, data=data)                                   


prediction<- predict(lm.1, data) 
prediction

check_model=postResample(pred = prediction, obs = data$ResponseVariable)
check_model
```

For my real dataset I will make a prediction based on my test set but for simplicity I just use the trainingset here as well.

I would like to make a prediction with the help of the fixed effects that I found. But it does not seem to match the fixed effect right, anyone who knows how to use this `fe$effects`?

```
prediction_fe<- predict(lm.1, data) + fe$effect
```

Comment: The `predict` function should use the fixed effects from the model. What do you mean when you ask "But it does not seem to match the fixed effect right"? How does it not match?

Comment: Probably not central to your question, but I get this error: could not find function "postResample"

Comment: Although this may alter what you mean by "fixed effects," you could just add Year to the lm? That is: lm(ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2 + Year, data=data). Do you think using lfe you will get a practically significant prediction?

Comment: The fe found fixed effects for 2000 till 2002. But I can't figure out how I could use these fixed effects in my prediction. So with "match" I actually meant how I could use the fixed effect in the prediction so that the fixed effect of the year 2000 is taken into account for the data of the year 2000.

Comment: @dca, I think postResample() is from the library(caret).

Comment: @dca, I could indeed add Year to the linear model. But I also have the variable "Country" for which I would like to find the fixed effects. And since Country is not numerical I thought that the fixed effect model would be a nice way to model. Is there another way to take those fixed effects into account?

Comment: @ekstroem, do you know how can I take the fixed effects into the predict function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by taking the FE into the predict function. `predict` uses the fitted model from the `lm` object when making the prediction and thus it uses the coefficients from the fitted model based on the background covariates found in the `newdata` argument (your `data`). Thus, running `predict` on `lm.1` should give you the predicted values given the design matrix used for the fit. You don't need to add anything by hand.

Comment: Ok, that is clear, thanks! But for what could the fixed effect (FE) than be used? Or does it just tell us that there is a fixed effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few extra comments on your setup and the models that you are running.

The primary model you are fitting is

```
lm.1<-lm(ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2, data=data)
```

which yields

```
> lm.1
Call:
lm(formula = ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2, 
    data = data)

Coefficients:
         (Intercept)  ExplanatoryVariable1  ExplanatoryVariable2  
              0.8901                0.7857                0.1923
```

When you run the `predict` function on this model you get

```
> predict(lm.1)
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7 
2.060385 3.439410 6.164590 3.631718 1.659333 4.192205 7.752359
```

That corresponds to computing (for observation 1) : 0.8901 + 1*0.7857 + 2*0.1923 so the estimated fixed effects are used in the prediction. The `felm` model is slightly more complicated as it "factors out" the year component. The model fit is shown here

```
> felm(data = data, ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2 | Year)
ExplanatoryVariable1 ExplanatoryVariable2 
              0.9726               1.3262
```

Now this correspond to "correcting for" or conditioning on `Year` so you get the same result if you fit

```
> lm(data = data, ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2 + factor(Year))

Call:
lm(formula = ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2 + 
    factor(Year), data = data)

Coefficients:
         (Intercept)  ExplanatoryVariable1  ExplanatoryVariable2      factor(Year)2001  
             -2.4848                0.9726                1.3262                0.9105  
    factor(Year)2002  
             -7.0286
```

and then just throw away all but the coefficients for the explanatory variables. Thus, you cannnot go from the extracted fixed effects from `felm` and obtain the predictions (since you are lacking the intercept and all the year effects) - you can only see the effect sizes.

Hope this helps.