# Predicting QUICKLY using a regression with a large number of fixed effects

Tags: r, regression, panel, categorical-data

I want to use `R` to estimate a regression with a very large number of fixed effects.

I then what to use that regression to predict with a test data set.

However, this needs to be done very quickly because I want to bootstrap my standard errors and do this many times.

I know the `lfe` package in `R` can do this.  For example

```
reg=felm(Y~1|F1 + F2,data=dat)
```

Where dat is the data, `F1,F2` are columns of categorical variables (the fixed effects to be included).

`predict(reg,dat2)`, however, does not work with the lfe package...as has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491545/predict-method-for-felm-from-lfe-package).

Unfortunately `lm` is too slow as I have a very large numbers of fixed effects.

Comment: What is your question? If you are looking for another package or resource that would do this faster than `lm`, that seems *off-topic*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to speed this up is to extract the coefficients and perform the matrix operations manually.  E.g.:

```
xtrain <- data.frame(x1=jitter(1:1000), x2=runif(1000), x3=rnorm(1000))
xtest <- data.frame(x1=jitter(1:1000), x2=runif(1000), x3=rnorm(1000))
y <- -(1:1000)
fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=xtrain)

beta <- matrix(coefficients(fit), nrow=1)
xtest_mat <- t(data.matrix(cbind(intercept=1, xtest)))
predictions <- as.vector(beta %*% xtest_mat)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(as.vector(beta %*% xtest_mat),
               predict(fit, newdata = xtest))

Unit: microseconds
                          expr     min       lq      mean  median      uq      max neval cld
 as.vector(beta %*% xtest_mat)   8.140  10.0690  13.12173  12.372  15.852   26.292   100  a 
 predict(fit, newdata = xtest) 635.413 657.2515 745.94840 673.009 763.166 2363.065   100   b
```

So you can see that direct matrix multiplication is ~50x faster than the predict function.

Comment: Sorry this does not answer the question.  F1 and F2 are categorical variables.  Fitting the lm with a high number of categorical variables is too costly, that was the point to begin with.

Comment: You didn't provide a reproducible example.  You also missed the point: do the predict operation manually will speed up, regardless of whether you use felm or lm.

Comment: You are correct I did not provide a reproducible example.  But, you need the fixed-effects (factor coefficients) to predict regardless of whether you do it manually or not.  I found a solution which involves getfe(felm_obejct), but again lm is too slow, that was the whole point.  It's not that predict is slow, it's that a regression with a large number of factors is slow.